# Static charge in polyethylene

Tags: electrostatics, charge, home-experiment

I work in a factory that manufactures polyethylene sheets, and I find that despite the fact that there are devices for preventing static electricity in the process (ion instrument, corona wire, etc.), the cylinders are loaded with static at high levels. How to unload the charger in such rolls if they are made of an insulating material and therefore can not be grounded.
How can I move the load from the rollers to the outside?

This is my first post, if writing is defined as homework question I apologize.

Comment: you can increase the humidity in the factory

Comment: I have in static issue inside bag (tubing) during extrusion. how we can remove it and what should be the root cause?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Once the surface of plastic is charged, the charge would not come off easily. The most practical way to remove it is to ionize the nearby air. The ionized air molecules of appropriate polarity will move toward the plastic and will neutralize the charge.

The rolls have charges trapped inside with no access of air, so they cannot be neutralized without unrolling.

Of course, the best approach would be to remove charges from the sheets before they wrapped into the rolls. This [article](https://www.aimcal.org/uploads/4/6/6/9/46695933/robinsonstaticmyth_abs.pdf) describes in detail how it could be done. One of the key points of the article is that dissipaters (static bars) have to be installed on the correct side of the sheet - otherwise you may end up with the sheets charged on both sides (polar charge). Interestingly, these opposite charges do not necessarily get neutralized when they face each other inside the roll, even for extended periods of time.

It is possible that some of the charge separation occurs even when a neutral roll is unwrapped, but, presumably the effect is not as severe.

So you can get yourself an electrostatic field meter and figure out where the charging occurs on the manufacturing floor and where the static bars should be installed to prevent the charges from getting into the rolls in the first place.

If a roll is already charged, you can potentially reduce the effects of static electricity during the unrolling by installing static bars on both sides of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in laser printers as well, the paper sheet get charged during the printing process. Leaving charge there could result in uncomfortable interaction of people and the paper. This is addressed by using a *static charge eliminator*: a comb with very fine conducting threads or brushes that touch the paper sheet at many points on a single line perpendicular to the direction of paper motion. The threads rub the paper as it gets out of the printer; due to close proximity of the conducting threads and the paper, the threads and then the comb is able to collect and leak out excessive charge from the paper. The comb is probably grounded. You can perhaps build such comb for your plastic sheets or search for a similar product.